# pass value from page 1 to page 2 and display the value

Tags: php

this my id num column with a value

```
 <td>ID NUMBER:</td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="txtEmpID" value="<?php echo $this->getArr['id']?>">
<input type="text" <?php echo (isset($this->postArr['EditMode']) && $this->postArr['EditMode']=='1') ? '' : 'disabled'?> name="txtEmployeeId2" value="<?php echo (isset($this->postArr['txtEmployeeId']))?$this->postArr['txtEmployeeId']:$edit[0][5]?>" maxlength="50">
```

how can to pass value from column `txtEmpID` to another page(reset.php) and display the value in the reset.php

this is reset.php

```
<tr>
    <td align="right">Employee ID&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left"><input name="staffid" type="text" class="textfield_login"
value="how to display the value from 1st page into here?"/></td>
      </tr>
```

help me please

Comment: you can pass this value through <form>, if you are using form.

Comment: u can use a form to post the value to reset.php, and access in reset.php as $_POST['txtEmpID']

Comment: You're supposed to use a <form> and you can either choose to use GET method, POST method or SESSIONS.

Comment: Were you already able to get `txtEmployeeId2` in reset.php? Then `txtEmpID` should be done at exactly the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the elements in a form and post the form a page.Then you can access the post data via `$_POST` if your method is post and `$_GET` if your method in form is get.

```
<form method="post" action="reset.php">
<td>ID NUMBER:</td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="txtEmpID" value="<?php echo $this->getArr['id']?>">
<input type="text" <?php echo (isset($this->postArr['EditMode']) && $this->postArr['EditMode']=='1') ? '' : 'disabled'?> name="txtEmployeeId2" value="<?php echo (isset($this->postArr['txtEmployeeId']))?$this->postArr['txtEmployeeId']:$edit[0][5]?>" maxlength="50">
</td>
</form>
```

In reset.php

```
echo $_POST['txtEmpID'];//Will contain the value of txtEmpID
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I can think of to do this.

### The first is to use a form.

```
<form action="reset.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" id="txtEmployeeId2" <?php echo (isset($this->postArr['EditMode']) && $this->postArr['EditMode']=='1') ? '' : 'disabled'?> name="txtEmployeeId2" value="<?php echo (isset($this->postArr['txtEmployeeId']))?$this->postArr['txtEmployeeId']:$edit[0][5]?>" maxlength="50">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

### The second

is to use Javascript/jQuery to get the value and pass it through the URL as an equivalent GET request.

However, you will need some sort of trigger to call the javascript function, like a button, for example.

```
<button onclick="sendValue()">Submit</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendValue()
    {
        parent.location = 'reset.php?txtEmployeeId2='+document.getElementById("txtEmployeeId2").value;
    }
```

Note that this will require you to add the ID attribute to your textbox.

For both solutions, you simply have to change the line in your reset.php file:

*This is assuming that both the name attribute of your input and the ID attribute are the same. Replace "txtEmployeeId2" with whatever name or ID you want to give to the text box inputs.*

```
<input name="staffid" type="text" class="textfield_login" value="how to display the value from 1st page into here?"/>
```

To

```
<input name="staffid" type="text" class="textfield_login" value="<?php echo $_GET["txtEmployeeId2"];?>"/>
```

Comment: David, I use 2nd method, take a look on this `function open_win()
{
window.open("http://localhost/ESSLASCREST_DEV_vQA_01/templates/hrfunct/resetPass.php","_blank","toolbar=yes, location=center, directories=no, status=no, menubar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=yes, width=400, height=400");
}` How can I getElementById in this function?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use session. (`$_SESSION` superglobal array)